# Remove both number and chapter but keep in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, titlesec, tocloft

I am using `\documentclass{book}` with both packages `tocloft` and `titlesec`.

I can't figure out if there is a way to remove both numbering and 'Chapter' (e.g "Introduction") from my `\chapter`'s, but keep them in ToC (e.g "Chapter 1: Introduction")

So far I've managed either removing number (e.g "Chapter Introduction") or 'Chapter'.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{plain}


%CHAPTER FORMAT
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering\Huge\bfseries}
{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
{\Huge\bfseries}
{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\LARGE}
{}{1em}{}

%TABLE OF CONTENTS 
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\small}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Contents}
\title{Pax Romana}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Chp1}
\chapter{Chp2}
\end{document}
```

These give me "Chapter 1 Introduction" and "1 Introduction" in ToC.
If possible in `book`, I need to achieve "Introduction" and "Chapter 1: Introduction" in ToC.

Any guidance?

Comment: Remove `\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter`. Is that what you want?

Comment: partly yes....that removed numbering from chapters.
 But in ToC I still got "1 Intro" ... Know perhaps how to make it 
"Chapter 1: Intro" ?

Comment: It is easy to do using `titletoc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}   %% for demo
%CHAPTER FORMAT
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering\Huge\bfseries}
{}{20pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0mm}{-20pt}{40pt}    %% adjust -20pt as you want

%TABLE OF CONTENTS
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength\cftchapnumwidth{6em}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter~}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{:}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Introduction}
  \kant
\end{document}
```

[image]